# Using XSD schema, is there a way to require certain attribute values in a series of complex type?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, unique

My problem: I'm using XSD to validate some XML on a service. I can require uniqueness, but that's not good enough: to keep a clean architecture, *I'd like to require in the XSD) that certain name/value pairs are required to appear once.

In sample data and schema below, the values of the Name attributes in the DataElement elements are required to be unique in the XSD. XSD does this with the 'unique' element

Is there a way for the validation engine to apply XSD to require that those values in the Name attributes appear exactly once per document? My reason is that some of those name/value pairs are required, and I'd rather find errors sooner rather than later. XSD is ideal, declarative, simple.

The closest I can find is the 'all' element of XSD, but that doesn't seem to help with complex types.

The data sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckRunLaunch xmlns="http://www.metaautomation.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CheckRunData>
    <DataElement Name="OriginMachine" Value="mattsurface" />
    <DataElement Name="PathAndFileToRunner" Value="c:\\" />
    <DataElement Name="DestinationMachine  " Value="mattsurface" />
    <DataElement Name="CheckJobSpecGuid   " Value="a24e2664-a901-4b50-a43e-f2d9aeaef0ff" />
    <DataElement Name="CheckJobRunGuid    " Value="3a1b815f-a862-4293-8d93-cbbdd802df1a" />
    <DataElement Name="CheckMethodRunGuid " Value="df58d8cb-ba00-47da-8a87-efffcb23594e" />
    <DataElement Name="CheckMethodName    " Value="WebPageFeedbackCheck" />
    <DataElement Name="CheckMethodGuid    " Value="EEEC8413-32E5-490B-AFD9-A01AD2CED9E6" />
  </CheckRunData>
</CheckRunLaunch>
```

The schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="CheckRunDataElementNameType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="PathAndFileToRunner"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="DestinationMachine"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="CheckJobSpecGuid"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="CheckJobRunGuid"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="CheckMethodRunGuid"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="CheckMethodName"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="OriginMachine"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="CheckMethodGuid"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="CheckRunLaunch">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="CheckRunData" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="8" maxOccurs="12" name="DataElement">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="Name" type="CheckRunDataElementNameType" use="required"  form="qualified"/>
                  <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
          <xs:unique name="NoMoreThanOneValueForGivenName">
            <xs:selector xpath="DataElement"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@Name"/>
          </xs:unique>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: If you're using XSD 1.1 you can use an xs:assert to ensure that a name value always exsists.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... You actually want the use of the pair (Name, Value) to be unique? Then if we find (`Name="CheckJobSpecGuid", Value="a24e2664-a901-4b50-a43e-f2d9aeaef0ff"`) twice, an error need to be raised, but (`Name="CheckJobSpecGuid", Value="a24e2664-a901-4b50-a43e-f2d9aeaef0ff"`) and (`Name="CheckJobSpecGuid", Value="df58d8cb-ba00-47da-8a87-efffcb23594e"`) both in the same document will be allowed?

Comment: No, the @Name is unique. See the element 'unique' in the XSD above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some namespaces issues, because the `xpath` in the `<xs:selector>` won't retrieve the elements in the correct namespace regarding the XML instance.

You need to modify your schema that way:

1. the root element should declare the *http://www.metaautomation.com* namespace you are working in:

   ```
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.metaautomation.com"
        xmlns="http://www.metaautomation.com">
   ```
2. then update your `<xs:unique>` declaration that way, if you need the *Name* to be used once:

   ```
   <xs:unique name="NoMoreThanOneValueForGivenName">
       <xs:selector xpath="ma:DataElement" xmlns:ma="http://www.metaautomation.com"/>
       <xs:field xpath="@Name"/>
   </xs:unique>
   ```

   or that way, if you want to check the **pair** (`@Name`, `@Value`) to be used once:

   ```
   <xs:unique name="NoMoreThanOneValueForGivenName">
       <xs:selector xpath="ma:DataElement" xmlns:ma="http://www.metaautomation.com"/>
       <xs:field xpath="@Name"/>
       <xs:field xpath="@Value"/>
   </xs:unique>
   ```